# why /proc/net/udp is showing wrong rx_queue size in CentOS server?

Tags: centos, java, udp, buffer

I have a java server application.

```
    while(true)
    {
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        process(receivePacket);
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);  // sleep for 10s
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It receives and processes 1 UDP packet / 10 sec.

If I send 10 UDP packets to the server processes 1 packet and then goes to sleep for 10s. so I get the 10th packet's response after 100s.

If I do this is server1 with CentOS release 6.4 (Final).

```
Server 1: cat /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
 110: 00000000:10AE 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 85635445 2 ffff880836e6d100 0       
 111: 00000000:10AF 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 85635446 2 ffff88083913a1c0 0       
 115: 00000000:15B3 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00004FC8 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 390649369 2 ffff880434ae7440 0      
 117: 02FE6341:0035 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 353480394 2 ffff8808367f9040 0
```

If I do this same thing in server 2:

```
Server 2: cat /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
   4: FCA9C11F:C36F 8C719AC6:0035 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2983494501 2 ffff880169aff4c0 0     
   5: FCA9C11F:D3F0 8C719AC6:0035 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2983494485 2 ffff8801b9bbedc0 0     
  16: 7A52BB59:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438608536 2 ffff8807656764c0 0     
  16: A2EE0D55:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438608045 2 ffff88077ccdd7c0 0     
  16: A58F466D:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    38        0 2438607809 2 ffff8801129f6240 0
```

They are both centos servers and as we can see that the server1's rx_queue buffer is increasing as the application is processing packets slower than data is coming to the server.

I did this exact same thing in server2 but in server2 the rx_queue is not increasing.
what am I doing/understanding wrong?

Comment: What kernel version on the two servers?

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernel 4.15.0-38).  But it doesn't happen on my Debian 9.5 (kernel 4.9.110-3) box.  Seems to be a bug in newer kernels?

A simple way to reproduce the problem is with netcat.  client and server can be local or on different boxes.

1. Run netcat server in one terminal: nc -u -l 1234
2. Run netcat client in another terminal: nc -u 127.0.0.1 1234
3. type a short message "a" in the client and press enter.
4. in a third terminal check the recv-q lengths: netstat -plan | grep 1234

On Ubuntu the receiving udp socket will have a non-empty recv-q (768 bytes for a 2 byte message) even though netcat has read the message from the socket and printed it.  I have ween the recv-q keep growing until about 52k, then it resets back to zero.

On Debian the recv-q is always zero as long as the udp socket is drained faster then packets are received.

Also found this kernel bug report: [UDP rx_queue incorrect calculation in /proc/net/udp](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199963)

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me being new to this part of StackExchange so I'm posting an answer instead of a comment.

I'm getting the same problem as @Neopallium, on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` (kernel `4.15.0-36`). From my testing, artificially setting `net.core.rmem_max=26214400` and `net.core.rmem_default=26214400` (that is, `25MB` respectively) and running my UDP server application with no UDP datagram backlogs throughout the test, I see the `rx_queue` counter go up to about `00000000:006xxxxx` or `~6MB+` and suddenly then the counter resets to `0`. This is at about `1/4` of the `net.core.rmem_max` before the counter resets. On `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` the default values of `net.core.rmem_default` and `net.core.rmem_max` is `212992` and hence it's no surprise @Neopallium is seeing his counter go up to about `52k` (about `1/4` of `212k` before it resets.

Here's the output of the application in `/proc/net/udp` nearing the point of reset:

```
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops
 1256: 00000000:7530 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00632240 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 94457826 2 0000000000000000 0
```

Here's the screeny of my grafana socket graph over the last 45 mins:

[image]
Like @Neopallium I'm inclined to believe it's a kernel bug.